# Como evitar redundância de código nesses dois métodos sendo que um possui um parâmetro IEnumerable<> e outro não?

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, genéricos

Como eu posso simplificar esses dois métodos de forma a impedir repetição de código?

Método 1, com a primeira expressão tendo uma propriedade genérica do tipo IEnumerable<>:

```
public GenericDAO<TModel> LeftJoin<TProperty>(
    Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> joinMember, 
    Expression<Func<TProperty, TModel, bool>> filter)
    where TProperty : class
{
    var joinMemberMetadata = new Mapping.MapperClass<TProperty>().DoMapper();
    var joinMemberExpression = joinMember.Body as dynamic;
    var filterExpression = filter as dynamic;

    var paramThisModel = filterExpression.Parameters[0].ToString();
    var paramJoinMember = filterExpression.Parameters[1].ToString();

    _query = _query.Trim() + " left join " + joinMemberMetadata.TableName + " as " + 
        joinMemberExpression.Member.Name + " on ";

    _query += filterExpression.Body.ToString()
        .Replace(paramThisModel, _metadataOfClass.TableName)
        .Replace(paramJoinMember, joinMemberExpression.Member.Name)
        .Replace("==", "=")
        .Replace("&&", "and");

    return this;
}
```

Com esse método eu posso utilizar expressão lambda em uma propriedade de tipo lista, assim:

```
libroDAO.Query().LeftJoin(livro => livro.Autores, ...)
```

Método 2, a primeira expressão desse método já não possui o IEnumerable<>:

```
public GenericDAO<TModel> LeftJoin<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> 
    joinMember, Expression<Func<TProperty, TModel, bool>> filter)
    where TProperty : class
{
    var joinMemberMetadata = new Mapping.MapperClass<TProperty>().DoMapper();
    var joinMemberExpression = joinMember.Body as dynamic;
    var filterExpression = filter as dynamic;

    var paramThisModel = filterExpression.Parameters[0].ToString();
    var paramJoinMember = filterExpression.Parameters[1].ToString();

    _query = _query.Trim() + " left join " + joinMemberMetadata.TableName + " as " + 
        joinMemberExpression.Member.Name + " on ";

    _query += filterExpression.Body.ToString()
        .Replace(paramThisModel, _metadataOfClass.TableName)
        .Replace(paramJoinMember, joinMemberExpression.Member.Name)
        .Replace("==", "=")
        .Replace("&&", "and");

    return this;
}
```

Com esse método eu posso fazer a mesma coisa para propriedades de classes simples:

```
livroDAO.Query().LeftJoin(livro => livro.Editora, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

O parâmetro `joinMember` e os parametro genérico `TProperty` só são usados nas primeiras duas linhas de ambos os métodos. Então podemos extrair todas as outras linhas para um método comum.

```
public GenericDAO<TModel> LeftJoin<TProperty>(
    Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> joinMember, 
    Expression<Func<TProperty, TModel, bool>> filter)
    where TProperty : class
{
    var joinMemberMetadata = new Mapping.MapperClass<TProperty>().DoMapper();
    var joinMemberExpression = joinMember.Body as dynamic;

    LeftJoin(joinMemberMetadata, joinMemberExpression, filter);
}

public GenericDAO<TModel> LeftJoin<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> 
    joinMember, Expression<Func<TProperty, TModel, bool>> filter)
    where TProperty : class
{
    var joinMemberMetadata = new Mapping.MapperClass<TProperty>().DoMapper();
    var joinMemberExpression = joinMember.Body as dynamic;

    LeftJoin(joinMemberMetadata, joinMemberExpression, filter);
}

private GenericDAO<TModel> LeftJoin<TProperty>(
    Mapper<TProperty> joinMemberMetadata, //Nota: eu nao sei qual e' o tipo retornado por .DoMapper
    dynamic joinMemberExpression,
    Expression<Func<TProperty, TModel, bool>> filter)
    where TProperty : class
{
    var filterExpression = filter as dynamic;

    var paramThisModel = filterExpression.Parameters[0].ToString();
    var paramJoinMember = filterExpression.Parameters[1].ToString();

    _query = _query.Trim() + " left join " + joinMemberMetadata.TableName + " as " + 
        joinMemberExpression.Member.Name + " on ";

    _query += filterExpression.Body.ToString()
        .Replace(paramThisModel, _metadataOfClass.TableName)
        .Replace(paramJoinMember, joinMemberExpression.Member.Name)
        .Replace("==", "=")
        .Replace("&&", "and");

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public GenericDAO<TModel> LeftJoin<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> 
    joinMember, Expression<Func<TProperty, TModel, bool>> filter)
    where TProperty : class
{
    return LeftJoin(_ => new List<TProperty> { joinMember }, filter);
}
```

Isso não funciona:

> Error 1   The best overloaded Add method 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(TProperty)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments    D:\Projects\GenericDAO\GenericDAO\GenericDAO.cs 125 56  GenericDAO
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'TProperty'  D:\Projects\GenericDAO\GenericDAO\GenericDAO.cs 125 56  GenericDAO

Já isso funciona:

```
return LeftJoin(x => new List<TProperty>(), filter);
```

[image: Teste do método]

Desculpem, não sou cadastrado e por isso não posso positivar respostas boas e nem negativar respostas ruins, muito menos aprovar uma resposta aceita.

Comment: E porque não se cadastrar? É tão fácil, nem precisa preencher nenhum cadastro.